# Как сгруппировать одинаковые данные?

Tags: javascript

Нужна помощь с группировкой данных.

К примеру есть массив с данными

`[{value: 25},{value: 25}, {value: 22}, {value: 25}]`

подскажите что нужно сделать чтобы сгруппировать данные и получить на выходе такой массив ? + и еще который содержит groupCount: кол одинаковых обьектов

`[{value: 25, groupCount: 3},{value: 22, groupCount: 1}]`

Answer (score 3):

```js
var arr = [{value: 25}, {value: 25}, {value: 22}, {value: 25}]

var map = Object.create(null)
for (var x of arr) (map[x.value] = map[x.value] || []).push(x)
console.log(map)

var res = []
for (var k of Object.keys(map)) res.push({ value: +k, count: map[k].length })
console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

```js
var arr = [{value: 25}, {value: 25}, {value: 22}, {value: 25}]

var map = Object.create(null)
for (var x of arr) map[x.value] = ~~map[x.value] + 1
console.log(map)

var res = []
for (var k of Object.keys(map)) res.push({ value: +k, count: map[k] })
console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const group = data => {
  const counts = data.reduce(
    (rslt, { value }) => rslt.set(value, ~~rslt.get(value) + 1)
  , new Map()); 
  return [...counts.entries()].map(
    ([value, groupCount]) => ({ value, groupCount })
  ); 
}; 

// test
const result = group([{value: 25}, {value: 25}, {value: 22}, {value: 25}]); 
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Правда, надо придумать что-то получше, чем

`return [...Object.entries(obj).sort()].join();`

```js
const arr = [{value: 25}, {value: 25}, {value: 22}, {value: 25}, {value: 22}];

function check(obj) {
  return [...Object.entries(obj).sort()].join();
}

function reducer(curr, prev) {
  if (curr[check(prev)]) {
    curr[check(prev)].groupCount++
  } else {
    curr[check(prev)] = {groupCount: 1, ...prev};
  }
  return curr;
}

const counter = arr.reduce(reducer, {});
console.log(Object.values(counter));
```

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```js
var values = [{value: 25},{value: 25}, {value: 22}, {value: 25}]; // формируем массив объектов

function filterItems(query) { // пишем функцию для работы с массивом
let newArray = []; // создаем array для возврата
query.forEach(function(each) { // для каждого объекта изначального массива делаем проверку
if(newArray.some(r => r.value == each.value) == false){ // проверяем есть ли объект в массиве для возврата
   let tmp = query.filter(item => item.value == each.value); // собираем массив из элементов с одинаковым значением value
   let topush = {}; // создаем объект для помещения в array для возврата.
   topush.value = each.value; // записываем value
   topush.groupCount = tmp.length; // записываем количество повторений
   newArray.push(topush); // помещаем объект в array для возврата
}
}); 
return newArray; // возвращаем готовый array
}
var result = filterItems(values); // отдаем функции массив для работы и помещаем результат в переменную result
console.log(result); // смотрим на результат
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот Вам еще такой вариант:

```js
let arr = [{value: 25}, {value: 25}, {value: 22}, {value: 25}];

let all = arr.map(el => el.value);
let count = v => all.filter(i => i === v).length;
let uniq = [...new Set(all)]; 
let res = uniq.map(v => ({value: v, groupCount: count(v)}));

console.log(res);
```